# MSI installer unable to close my application automatically

Tags: c#, wix, trayicon

When our WIX installer attempts to uninstall I get the following prompt

[image: Application must be closed dialog]

If I click ok I see the following...

[image]

This is saying our system tray icon is not closing.  Our tray icon program is written in C# to be a single global instance of our application (only one instance can run at once).  Any idea what would cause this?

Is there some event I should expect to have fired in my C# code when the process is soft killed?

Comment: Any information about how eThor gets started and stopped?  Does eThor respond to system events?  While less than ideal, we had to create an application called "KillSwitch" to kill all the processes for us.  Windows 7 and UAC can prevent process Kill events from doing their job.

Comment: Another thought would be whether eThor starts up automatically.  You may have killed one process, but another one takes its place.  This is, unfortunately, a common installer problem.

Comment: Look at integrating with Restart Manager, that might be what you're looking for. I believe that particular dialog really means that it's going to send restart manager messages to them to see if they close down, and if they don't handle them then they won't automatically shut down and Windows won't restart them after the install. The point of integrating with RM is to avoid a reboot.